# Can I have multiple inputs in a form in CodeIgniter URL?

Tags: codeigniter

I know that CodeIgniter already elegantly handles URL's. What I have is a form with multiple elements (date, keyword, location = optional). Is it possible to set up CI to create a URL that looks like:

mysite.com/class/function/date/keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CodeIgniter's form helper, it sends your form data via POST, so you can't easily have your field's value displayed in the url.

What you could have, though, is a controller method that collects your form data and redirects to the url you want.

If you need further clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`anchor`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function by passing the relevant info to it.